# Substring Command is Ignoring spaces in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

What i am trying to do is produce substring out of a string. But the issue is with the spaces.

The problem is with the spaces in the string.

The substring includes the spaces whenever the space falls in between two characters, but not when the space  is at the beginning of the substring to be extracted.

Below example will explain it:

i am using " **echo ${string:position:length}** "

INPUT: "vishal singh"

> 1. when position = 6 and length = 4;; then OUTPUT = "sin"

its ignoring the space here

> 2. when position = 5 and length = 4;; then OUTPUT = "l si"

but not here

Note: I need the space in the first example. And I am new to shell script.

```
export LC_ALL=C
readarray -t ar
read pos
read len
l=${#ar}
if [ "$l" -gt 100 ] || [ "$l" -lt 1 ]
then
 exit
fi
for index in ${!ar[@]}
do 
 echo ${ar[index]:$pos:$len} 
done
```

Comment: `${#ar}` is equivalent to `${#ar[0]}`; did you want `${#ar[@]}` instead?

Comment: Also, `readarray` populates `ar` with *lines* of input, not individual words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quote the expression in which you need to preserve whitespace.

```
echo "${ar[index]:$pos:$len}"
```

Otherwise, word splitting is applied to parameter expansion which removes whitespace. See *Word Splitting* in `man bash` (emphasis mine):

> The shell scans the results  of  **parameter  expansion**,  command  substitution,  and
>          arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting.

Comment: In shell scripts, you almost always want to put double-quotes around variable references. This is just one of the many ways leaving them off can cause trouble.

Comment: thank you guys.  such silly mistake from my side. @GordonDavisson will remember to quote variable from now on.

Comment: Thank you @choroba. Isee not a big deal but caused me trouble. Small things like these  matter  a lot. This will be a lesson. Thanks again.